# Impact of "INVALIDATE METADATA" on "COMPUTE STATS" in Impala

Tags: impala

I understand that running INVALIDATE METADATA statement on a table flushes its metatdata. Will it **also** invalidate any meta data created by the COMPUTE STATS statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `INVALIDATE METADATA` just clears the cached metadata in the Impala Catalog. Table and column statistics are persisted in the Hive Metastore.